# Object Detection - Auto labelling

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, object-detection

I have several images with multiple objects in each. The size of the set of objects is finite (around 20). I want to detect and classify all objects in an image.

I'm new to this and wanted to use TensorFlow but from what I understand: Training a TensorFlow model requires a labelled/annotated database of images. I have a lot of images and do not want to individually label the bounding boxes in each.

I am not concerned with the value of the labels just that the objects of one class are given the same label.

How do I go about inputing a set of images and the model automatically detecting different objects and training. What alternatives to TensorFlow do I have for this? or online tools?

Comment: This is a research problem, by not having labels you pass from a simple problem into a currently not solved one. Consider that if there were methods that learn object detectors without labels, then why would these examples need labels at all?. Just get labels.

Comment: Neural networks NEEDS the labels. But you might have some images with salient objects in them and could find them with some not-real-time-conventional-image-processing methods. Put some sample image here so maybe we could help.

Answer (score 0):

I may add to Matias comment, you do not need to annotate all of your images. Annotate a subset and use it to train your detector to automatically label the rest.

Comment: What if you have multiple labels per image and you need one feature / image to train ? How can it be solved ?